# Mach-o-linker, duplicate error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Everything was well, until I imported a .m file, then I got the apple-o-mach linker error that has something to do with duplicates - here is the error message.

```
   Ld /Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess\ Timer.app/Chess\ Timer normal i386
cd "/Users/Wills/Desktop/XCode projects/Chess Timer"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess\ Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess\ Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/Chess\ Timer.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess\ Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess\ Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/Chess\ Timer_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess\ Timer.app/Chess\ Timer

duplicate symbol _callGameBuffer in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _gameBufferReady in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._hours in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._minutes in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._secondsLeft in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._timeLeftstring in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._player2Button in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._player2Timer in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
 duplicate symbol _timeLeft in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _buffer1 in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
 duplicate symbol _alerted in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._timeToShow in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._timeToShowString in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _timeLeft2 in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._player1Timer in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _buffer2 in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController.player2Timer in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController.player1Timer in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._callGameReadyBuffer in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._gameBufferReady in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._buffer1 in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._buffer2 in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._timeLeft in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._timeLeft2 in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._alerted in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._player1Button in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController._playButton in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in:
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/Wills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chess_Timer-cfqcwankpfmmxwheqgqaivhnjtzf/Build/Intermediates/Chess Timer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Chess Timer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
ld: 29 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know there are already a few posts on the "Apple-O-Mach-Linker" error, already, but none of them really explain WHY this error happens and HOW you can fix it in a generalised way, so I can not only fix it this time, but fix it every time the error occurs. Thanks a lot. Wills

Comment: imported the .m file ? Try importing the .h instead.

Comment: Why did you import .m file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing means the imported text file is essential copied into the destination file before being passed to the compiler, its like a macro where the macro is what ever is in that file. So now you compiler is being given the contents of the source file to compile twice. .h files can be imported because we only put declaration into .h files and the definitions into .m files, having multiple declaration of something is fine, as long as you have only one definition. For example you can declare a c function in a .h file and so in effect have it declared multiple places where ever that .h file is imported or included, but the function can only be defined in one .m or .c file.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda get it now.